# Width procent and overflow scroll

Tags: css, scroll, width, overflow

I have one div with some code inside (like textarea) and i want to fix to 99 % from parent element. It ok, but if the code is to big i need to put overflow-x:scroll to not get out from parent element.

Because i use width:99%, i can't use overflow-x:scroll.

I don't want to put width:700px or 500 or whatever because i don't now the client resolution and i really want to see the maxim width as this div.

Sorry for my bad language.

Some advice please ?

Thanks.

Comment: why can't you use `overflow-x:scroll` ?

Comment: Because this div has width:99%

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i forgot about white-space:pre.

Try this code, and you will see :

```
<style>
div {width:99%; border:1px solid grey; white-space:pre; overflow:x-scroll}
</style>

<div>
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this one?

```
div {width:99%; border:1px solid grey; white-space:pre; overflow:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
    div {width:99%;
 border:1px solid grey;
 white-space:pre;
 overflow:x-scroll}
    </style>

    <div>
    test test test test test
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please sorry for my mistakes, and because i don't give all code.

Stil doesen't work because the parent element (table -> td) is flexible to :

```
<style> 
div {width:99%; border:1px solid grey; white-space:pre; overflow:auto;}
</style>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td> some stuff here </td>
<td>
<div>
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If somebody have another advice...